# using binarySearch to do a paircount of integers in a java int array

Tags: java, binary-search

I tried using `Arrays.binarySearch` to find the number of pairs of ints in an array.In the following array, a brute force algorithm will find 4 pairs..However the binarysearch version gives 3 which is the wrong answer.

brute force:

```
public static int brutePairCount(int[] a){
        int paircount = 0;
        int N = a.length;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
                if(a[i]==a[j] ){
                    paircount++;
                }
            }
        }
        return paircount;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = new int[]{12, 12, 23, 23, 45, 67, 75, 75, 85, 92, 111, 113, 113, 134, 142, 156};
    int cnt1 = brutePairCount(nums);
    System.out.println("pairs="+cnt1);
}
```

binarysearch:

```
public static int bsPairCount(int[] a){
        Arrays.sort(a);
        int paircount = 0;
        int N = a.length;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            int key = a[i];
            int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(a, key);
            if(idx > i){
                paircount++;
            }
        }
        return paircount;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = new int[]{12, 12, 23, 23, 45, 67, 75, 75, 85, 92, 111, 113, 113, 134, 142, 156};
    int cnt1 = bsPairCount(nums);
    System.out.println("pairs="+cnt1);
}
```

I found that the logic

```
if(idx > i){
   paircount++;
}
```

is the source of error.My debugger shows that ,at `i=11, key =113` ,the `binarysearch(key)` returns `11` itself,and so count is not incremented.

From the javadocs of `Arrays.binarySearch` :

> If the range contains multiple elements equal to the specified object,
>   there is no guarantee which one will be found.

I think I found the problem,but how do I solve this? my brain is a bit addled (lack of sleep:( )..Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Just don't use binarySearch. It's not the appropriate tool. Sort the array, then iterate and compare each value to its neighbour.

Comment: As you already have a sorted array (use of binary search indicates this) it is best to go with @JBNizet`s comment. This would give a O(n) solution